# Set every windows directory view as 'Large Icons' and 'group by type' as default in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way in Windows 7 to set the default view for every folder (existing as well as newly created) to be in 'Large Icons' and 'Group by type' Mode??

By default, right now it seems that every folder is in "Details" view mode. I've to go to that directory or folder, change the view mode to "Large Icons", than right-click and set "Group by type" to get what I want??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the view you want in one folder, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to get the menu bar, select `Tools` -> `Folder Options`. Go to the `View` tab and click *Apply to Folders*.

Comment: It doesn't seem to apply "Group by Type" though..